# Group cohomology with coefficients in regular representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I am quite new to group cohomology and want to get an intuition for it. It seemed natural to me to calculate the groups $H^p(G,\mathbb C(G))$, where $G$ is a group and $\mathbb C(G)$ is the vector space of functions on $G$.

Is there something we can say about this in general, i.e. vanishing results or expressing the cohomology in terms of $G$ itself?

Edit: I didn't accept the answer so far because i was hoping for a more hands-on approach. Maybe somebody can jump in?

Comment: Just a note: when $G$ is infinite, $\Bbb C(G)$ is not what I would call the regular representation of $G$, that would be the subrepresentation of all functions that are $0$ except at some finite subset of $G$, i.e. the module $\Bbb C[G]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a proof for the case $p=1$:

Let $z\in Z^1(G,G(\mathbb C))$. Define $f\in C^0(G,\mathbb C(G))=\mathbb C(G)$ by $f(g)=[z(g)] (1)$. 
Then $$[df(x)] (g) = (x\cdot f-f)(g) = f(gx)-f(x) \\
[z(gx)](1)-[z(x)](1)=[z(x)](g),$$
where for the last equaility we used that $z$ is a cocycle.

You can probably generalize this approach for an arbitrary $p$.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb C(G) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(G, \Bbb C) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z[G],\Bbb C)$ since $\Bbb Z[G]$ is a free $\Bbb Z$-module (and the action on $G$ corresponds to the action on the basis)

Thus $\Bbb C(G)$ is a coinduced module and we get $H^p(G,\Bbb C(G)) = 0$ for all $p>0$ (compare Thm. 1.5.7, p.15 in these notes: http://math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/groupcoh.pdf)

Note that we can replace $\Bbb C$ with any abelian group.

Comment: Sorry for my late comment. I took a look at the link, but unfortunately it was too complicated for me :D. Thanks, though. I will look at it again when I am more familiar with the topic.

Comment: @mathsta this is a consequence of "Shapiro's lemma" which is an important result that you'll find in most resources on group cohomology.